# Heckman's selection / switching model- selection variable as a regressor

Tags: r, model-selection

I am conducting some analyses on the effects of membership and the membership rank on income. Everyone in the sample can choose to apply to join an organization. The membership is given upon application. When voluntarily joining the organization, the member is also given a rank (numerically coded from 1 to 10) based on some unobservable characteristics.

The membership (yes or no) is observed for everyone. The members' rank is also observed. For non-members, the rank is coded as zero.

I also have a bunch of explanatory variables on everyone. Denote them as X.

To become a members is a selection process, so a section model is first applied to determine the membership, with the two switching models on income estimated in the second stage.

My question is (I am writing the codes in R), how should I specify the two switching models? Shall I specify the members' income as `income ~ membership + rank + X`, and the non-members' income as `income ~ membership + X`?